# Can I skip the "guitar hero" minigames?

Tags: night-in-the-woods

I just started playing Night in the Woods, and once I got home, I noticed there was a guitar in my bedroom. I interacted with it, and it started playing a guitar hero minigame... Which I immediately failed miserably at because I can't keep rhythm at all, certainly not at the pace the game wanted me to.

I know next to nothing about the game, just that it was recommended by several people in chat. However, if the game is full of minigames like this and at least one of them is needed to get to the good endings, I might as well switch to another game.

Does this game have rhythm minigames that are required to finish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**. You can skip all band segments with <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Start</kbd>. They are not required in any sense at all.

That said, I do recommend trying them. They're fun little segments, and the lack of preparation is intentional to put you in the head space of Mae who hasn't played in a long time, and doesn't even know the songs.

Comment: I think on Switch you can probably use + but I don't know